# Android: not shows all text of XML from URL

Tags: android, xml, url, text

I am creating the recovery of text using XML from a URL. I get the text. But I have a problem.

When the text of an item of the XML is large, in the TextView not shows all text of the XML.

What can be the error?

**ACTIVITY**

```
class tareaAsyncHorariosTarifas extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    XmlReader helper;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        helper = new XmlReader(color);
        helper.get();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (HorariosTarifasObj post : helper.posts) {
            builder.append(post.getHorarios());
        } 
        if(builder.toString().equals("")) {
            horario2.setText("-");
        } else {
            horario2.setText(Html.fromHtml(builder.toString()));
        }

        builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (HorariosTarifasObj post : helper.posts) {
            builder.append(post.getTarifas());
        }
        if(builder.toString().equals("")) {
            tarifa2.setText("-");
        } else {
            tarifa2.setText(Html.fromHtml(builder.toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

**XML READER**

```
public XmlReader(String color) {

    this.color = color;     
}

public void get() {

    try {
        SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

        XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
        reader.setContentHandler(this);

        InputStream inputStream = new URL(URL + color + ".xml").openStream();
        reader.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

    currTag = true;
    currTagVal = "";

    if (localName.equals("color")) {
        post = new HorariosTarifasObj();
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    currTag = false;

    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("horarios")) {
        post.setHorarios(currTagVal);

    } else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("tarifas")) {
        post.setTarifas(currTagVal);

    } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("color")) {
        posts.add(post);
    }
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {

    if (currTag) {
        currTagVal = currTagVal + new String(ch, start, length);
        currTag = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you recognize some limit on the text length? for example 8000 characters? Or 100 lines?

Comment: <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textViewTarifa2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                                android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                                android:text="Cargando..."
                                android:textSize="14sp" />

Comment: I mean the actual text in the app that is clipped

Comment: I charge many XML. They have different sizes. A text is cut with 700 characters aprox and other text with 800 is not cut...

Comment: and you are sure that `Html.fromHtml(builder.toString())` returns something that is longer than appears in the TextView? Maybe you can try to show the text in a WebView or save it to SD card to be sure the problem isn't somewhere else.